# How to map multiple objects from the same table with Dapper.net?

Tags: c#, sql, join, dapper

I have two SQL tables: Teams and Members. Each team contains 3 members, in the database the members' ids are stored.

[Sample Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTuTQ.png)

How could I map the Member objects into the Teams using the Dapper.NET ORM?

```py
public class Team
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public Member MemberA { get; set; }
    public Member MemberB { get; set; }
    public Member MemberC { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Teams t LEFT JOIN Members m ON t.MemberA=m.id AND t.MemberB=m.id AND t.MemberC=m.id";

    return m_connection.Query<Team, Member, Member, Member, Team>(sql, (t, m1, m2, m3) =>
    {
        t.MemberA = m1;
        t.MemberB = m2;
        t.MemberC = m3;

        return t;
    }, splitOn: "MemberA,MemberB,MemberC");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your team have a `List<Member>`?

Comment: This is more a Sql syntax problem than a Dapper one

Comment: @stuartd No, it's not a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your sql query to have a proper join with the Members Table.

Just change it to

```
string sql = @"SELECT t.ID, t.MemberA, m1.Id, m1.Name, 
                            t.MemberB, m2.Id, m2.Name, 
                            t.MemberC, m3.Id, m3.Name
               FROM Teams t LEFT JOIN Members m1 ON t.MemberA=m1.id 
                            LEFT JOIN Members m2 ON t.MemberB=m2.id
                            LEFT JOIN Members m3 ON t.MemberC=m3.id";
```

and your dapper code will work as you expect filling the three Member instance of every single Team retrieved.

Notice that when you use multimapping, you need to place the SplitOn elements in the proper place to have Dapper understand your requirement to create three different Member variables.

**Version for MS-Access**

```
string sql = @"SELECT t.ID, t.MemberA, m1.Id, m1.[Name], 
                            t.MemberB, m2.Id, m2.[Name], 
                            t.MemberC, m3.Id, m3.[Name]
               FROM (((Teams t LEFT JOIN Members m1 ON t.MemberA=m1.id) 
                            LEFT JOIN Members m2 ON t.MemberB=m2.id)
                            LEFT JOIN Members m3 ON t.MemberC=m3.id)";
```

Comment: Does this sql expression works with OleDbConnection too? Because I got a syntax error.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS Access database

Comment: Probably it is the column titled _Name_. It is a reserved keyword in MS-Access. Try to use _m1.[Name]....,m2.[Name],...,m3.[Name]_

Comment: Paste the query into Access and it should tell you what it doesn't like

Comment: Same message in Access: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: 't.MemberA=m1.id LEFT JOIN Members m2 ON t.MemberB=m2.id LEFT JOIN Members m3 ON t.MemberC=m3.i'.

Comment: Answer updated with the accepted syntax by MS-Access. It needs the parenthesys around the multiple join

Comment: Now the sql syntax seems good, both in access and c# the expression runs. But the Dapper query wouldn't map the m1, m2 and m3 objects, the Name and Id values still null.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem and you are correct. Now the Dapper query doesn't return anything for the Member instances. Now I have no answer to that, Let's wait to see if anyone from the Dapper team would look at this problem.

Comment: Further analysis shows that internally dapper executes the query and get all the data from the database, but something happens when it tries to 'deserialize' that data into the objects requires in the lambda expression. We need the help from the Dapper team now. Looking if there something already posted about this issue.